# Type conversion when copying properties with BeanUtils?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I use [`PropertyUtils.copyProperties`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/index.html) from Apache Commons BeanUtils to copy properties between two beans, now I encounter a problem: there is a same name field in two beans, one is `Long` type, the other is `Double` type, so can I use type converter to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object, Object) instead. 
It will use org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter to convert your values if necessary. See org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils.register(Converter, Class) for more details.

Many standard types have been registered automatically, see org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.